# Throws socket hang up error when send requests with request module

Tags: node.js, request

I have ran into a very very tricky situation, here is the story:

the code which using request module will always throw `[Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET'`, on the contrary, using http / urllib module is just ok~
Note: I tried to switch Node version from 0.12.x to 5.x, and even restarted my machine, BUT with no luck, same result.

```
const http = require('http');
const co = require('co');
const Q = require('q');
const request = require('request');
const urllib = require('urllib');
// const coRequest = require('co-request');

const URL = 'http://www.google.com';

co(function*() {
  try {
    http.get(URL, (res) => {
      console.log('res statusCode', res.statusCode);
    });
  } catch(err) {
    console.error('thrown from http', err);
  }

  try {
    yield Q.nfcall(request, URL);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error('thrown from request', err);
  }

  try {
    const res = yield Q.ninvoke(urllib, 'request', URL);
    console.log(res[1].statusCode);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error('thrown from urllib', err);
  }

}).catch(err => {
  console.error('error', err);
})
```

screenshot:

[image]

Any idea?

Should I do some clean-up, like a broken socket file descriptor?

Comment: I had the same issue but, other server is also managing by me. I was getting the Socket Hang up issue because no response sent from my other server and that was creating socket hang up. When I've handled the proper response for every request, the issue is resolved.

Comment: but I even have no chance to handle response, the error thrown as soon as request was made.

Comment: Sorry, guys~  
Eventually it turns out that my machine got a virus which interrupts the request...